# Named Default constraint for Identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I have following table creation script. I would like to have a named default constraint for the EmployeeID column to use Identity (1,1)

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(
    EmployeeID INT NOT NULL ,
    LastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FirstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_Employee PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    (
        EmployeeID ASC
    )
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE Employee ADD CONSTRAINT UDF_Employee_EmployeeID DEFAULT IDENTITY(1,1) FOR EmployeeID
GO
```

I am getting following error

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: DEFAULT makes the engine populate a value when none is provided. You didn't give the value you want it to use. If it's an IDENTITY field then you don't need DEFAULT.

Comment: `IDENTITY` is a column property, and not part of any constraint. It cannot be added or removed at any time other than when adding or dropping a column.

Comment: @JeroenMostert that's a great point too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee
(
     EmployeeID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1),
     LastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
     FirstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

     CONSTRAINT PK_Employee 
         PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (EmployeeID ASC)
)
```

`DEFAULT IDENTITY` is not proper syntax and since `IDENTITY` is a column property, not a constraint, you can't add it using `ALTER` (or at all after column creation).